# Looking for a document that describes SSME test failures

Tags: failure, reference-request, ssme, historical-data

At some point in the last 5 years I put together this matrix of Space Shuttle Main Engine test failures.  The last 6 columns are documents which describe some of the incidents in more or less detail. I got all the documents off the [NASA Technical Reports Server](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?N=0&Ntk=All&Ntx=mode%20matchallany&Ntt=What%20do%20you%20want%20to%20find%3F) (NTRS).

[image]

However, and I blame the ravages of advancing age, I no longer have the document known only by the mysterious nomenclature "AL-TR-898-013" and I can't currently find it on NTRS or anywhere else. Naturally, it's the one that contains the more or less complete list of incidents.

I know sometimes documents are removed from NTRS and that may well have happened here in which case I'm probably out of luck.

I've checked my computer backups but they only go back a year.

I'm guessing it's a Marshall Space Flight Center technical report, but if anyone can point me to a copy of this document - or even tell me what the title of it is -, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2+ years later, I finally found the document. My stupidity in mistyping the document number, plus a really non-intuitive title on the document, are what kept me from finding it for so long.

The real document number is **AL-TR-89-013** and its title is

> **CURRENT LAUNCH VEHICLE RELIABILITY PRACTICE
> AND
> DATA BASE ASSESSMENT
> VOLUME 1: EXECUTIVE
> SUMMARY AND REPORT BODY**

It can be downloaded from https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA213600.pdf

Answer (score 3):

See:
https://gandalf.azureedge.net/shuttle.html (If anybody knows the docents for Endeavour or Enterprise in Los Angeles or New York please pass this link to them)

Specifically to answer your question a couple of documents (I think the first one has pretty much the same table as you show):
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/NASA-TP-3653_A_History_of_Aerospace_Problems_Their_Solutions_Their_Lessons_19970001339.pdf

Supporting document:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/BCD-SSME-TR-87-33_Studies_And_Analysys_Of_The_SSME_19890009154.pdf

The table in the first document:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I know the first document well, but I am not familiar with the 2nd one. Will look through it to see if my mystery document is referenced.